# how to add confidence interval fillcontour using plotly express?

Tags: plotly, seaborn, plotly-python, confidence-interval, trendline

I am using plotly express to add trendline, now how to plot confidence interval like in seaborn regplot(),

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotly doesn't have confidence bands built in. However, since you want something like seaborn `regplot`, you can directly use regplot, extract the array representing the upper and lower bands, and then create the visualization in plotly.

The only thing is that in order to extract the confidence bands from regplot, you'll need to specify a `binwidth` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868292/extract-mean-and-confidence-intervals-from-seaborn-regplot). For the tips dataset, I used a binwidth of 5 to ensure that within each bin, there are enough points for a confidence band to be created (if you use a binwidth of 1, no confidence band will be calculated for sparser regions of the data)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="ols")

## use binning so that we can access the confidence intervals
binwidth = 5
x_max, x_min = max(df["total_bill"]), min(df["total_bill"])
x_bins = np.arange(x_min, x_max, binwidth)
sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", x_bins=x_bins, data=df, x_ci=95, fit_reg=None)

ax = plt.gca()
x = [line.get_xdata().min() for line in ax.lines]
y_lower = [line.get_ydata().min() for line in ax.lines]
y_upper = [line.get_ydata().max() for line in ax.lines]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x+x[::-1], # x, then x reversed
    y=y_upper+y_lower[::-1], # upper, then lower reversed
    fill='toself',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
    line=dict(color='rgba(255,255,255,0)'),
    hoverinfo="skip",
    showlegend=False
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Derek, that is awesome! I appreciate it

Comment: Derek, the confidence interval you created is kind of different from what seaborn created.  see above my plot

Comment: @roudan your plot likely looks different because the underlying data is different. if you look at the tips dataset, the line of best fit doesn't actually fit the data that well in some places, so you can have situations where the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval are not that evenly spaced around the line of best fit

Comment: This is ... not a confidence interval for the regression line.